# Number of models of the naturals and reals with and without CH

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis, nonstandard-models

The Wikipedia page on [true arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_arithmetic#Model-theoretic_properties) says that it has $2^\kappa$ models for each uncountable cardinal $\kappa$. This refers to the theory of all first-order statements of the naturals.

I'm curious how CH affects this (if it does at all). With the hyperreals, for instance, if we have CH, all of the various choices of ultrafilter on countable sequences of reals produce isomorphic structures. Do we get the same thing with the hypernaturals?

Basically, the questions are the following:

1. Without CH, how many $\mathfrak c$-sized models of the first-order theory of the naturals are there? And the reals?
2. With CH, how many models of both are there?
3. Does CH change how many different models *exist*, or does it only change how many different models are obtainable using the ultrapower construction?
4. When that Wikipedia page says "true arithmetic" has $2^\mathfrak{c}$ models of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, is there any implicit assumption being made about the status of CH?

Comment: If a theorem is provable in ZFC, then CH has no bearing on it.

Comment: And as a whole, CH has exactly no bearing on the value of $2^\frak c$.

Comment: Which theorem is provable in ZFC?

Comment: That TA is unstable and has $2^\kappa$ models in any uncountable cardinality (indeed, *any* infinite cardinality).

Comment: Ok, so you are saying CH changes how many of these different models one can get from building ultrapowers, not the total cardinality of models which exist at all?

Comment: The continuum-theory tag isn't appropriate; it's for the study of continua (= compact connected metric spaces), not CH.